# How do I Sort Cells from different worksheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am posting here again. I have been working on my result work sheet for a time now. I have two worksheets for two different groups of students. I am making a tabulation sheet for all the students.

Problem is I am going to make a list of Failed and passed students from Worksheet-Humanities and Business studies to other worksheets named passed and failed worksheets.

Here is a screenshot of my current worksheet -
[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

I need the formula / function for sorting this type of data from selected cell and transfer it to another worksheet.

Waiting for your reply
Thanks in advance
Imran